# Request Google Calendar event using start time and end time

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

can we add date time filter to fetch event from google calendar

```
require_once '../../src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../../src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("xxxx");
$client->setClientId('xxxxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('1Z1Wd1M18yF3LXMVVPqoZA9S');
$client->setRedirectUri('xxxxxx');
$client->setDeveloperKey('<key>');
$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
$events = $cal->events->listEvents('<calender_id>');

var_dump($events);
```

Comment: have you tried using timeMin and timeMax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Calendar API [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) has two options

> **timeMax**   
>     Upper bound (exclusive) for an event's start time to
>   filter by. Optional. The default is not to filter by start time. Must
>   be an RFC3339 timestamp with mandatory time zone offset, e.g.,
>   2011-06-03T10:00:00-07:00, 2011-06-03T10:00:00Z. Milliseconds may be
>   provided but will be ignored. 
>  **timeMin**    
>  Lower bound
>   (inclusive) for an event's end time to filter by. Optional. The
>   default is not to filter by end time. Must be an RFC3339 timestamp
>   with mandatory time zone offset, e.g., 2011-06-03T10:00:00-07:00,
>   2011-06-03T10:00:00Z. Milliseconds may be provided but will be
>   ignored.

By sending these you should be able to limit your results.